# Setting Manual charset in PHP casing internal server error

Tags: php, mysql

I my project the data stored in mysql DB is in Bangla language. To handle Bangla i need utf-8 unicode encoding. So i have manually set encoding in php file-

```
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

But on adding it it is showing 500 Internal Server Error. 
The project link is 
http://www.goraifilms.com/heros/showdata.php

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the [`set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) function. Also what do the error logs say?

Comment: See also: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Comment: `[10-Oct-2017 03:19:57 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /home/goraifilms/public_html/heros/connection.php on line 8`

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" means the PHP code failed, usually because of a fatal error. I suspect `$connect` is not a [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) object. How do you initialize it?

Comment: [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) and [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqli.php) are different sets of **incompatible** functions. MySQL is an old PHP extension that was [deprecated in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.requirements.php). **Don't use it!**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
//assuming $connect is your connection
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: Still same problem